# BootstrapTable2 pagination number of items per page drop down not displaying

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4, react-bootstrap, react-bootstrap-table

I'm using [BootstrapTable2](https://react-bootstrap-table.github.io/react-bootstrap-table2/docs/getting-started.html) with Bootstrap4. Everything works except that when I click on the number of items per page, the drop down to select the number of items doesn't display.

Here is my code (it is based off of this [example](https://react-bootstrap-table.github.io/react-bootstrap-table2/storybook/index.html?selectedKind=Pagination&selectedStory=Basic%20Pagination%20Table&full=0&addons=1&stories=1&panelRight=0&addonPanel=storybook%2Factions%2Factions-panel):

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import BootstrapTable from 'react-bootstrap-table-next';
import paginationFactory from 'react-bootstrap-table2-paginator';

render(){

        const columns =  [
                      {
                          text: "Item",
                          dataField: 'Title',
                          sort: true
                      },
                      {
                          text: "Quantity",
                          dataField: 'Quantity',
                          sort: true
                      },
                      {
                          text: "Needed By",
                          dataField: 'DateNeeded',
                          sort: true
                      },
                      {
                          text: "Requested By",
                          dataField: 'RequesterUsername',
                          sort: true
                      }
                  ]
        return(
            <div>
                <script src="webjars/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

                <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
                <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

                {this.state.data != null && <BootstrapTable keyField='id' bootstrap4 data={ this.state.data } columns={ columns } pagination={ paginationFactory() } />}
            </div>
            )

    }
```

Here are my current versions:

```
"bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
"jquery": "^3.5.0",
"popper.js": "^1.16.1",
"react": "^16.13.1",
"react-bootstrap": "^1.0.1",
"react-bootstrap-table-next": "^4.0.1",
"react-bootstrap-table2-paginator": "^2.1.2",
```

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that the dropdown menu was actually being cutoff because overflow was hidden.

Adding this css solved the problem:

```
    .dropdown{
        overflow: visible !important;
    }
```